# I have part of string i need to get full string from VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I need to extract full string from excel cell, through VBA. I just know a part of string
Eg: somestr_part
ill search _part in excel. It should extract somestr_part into a variable. 
Plz give VBA code to do so.

Thank you,
KCSR

Comment: " Plz give VBA code to do so."... Welcome to Stack Overflow. Your question seems totally unclear to me. Would be better if you clarify it. Please read
FAQ, -> http://stackoverflow.com/tour How to Ask -> http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask and help center -> http://stackoverflow.com/help
as a start.

Comment: We are here to help, not to provide programming services.

Answer (score 0):

x = mid("string you're searching" , InStr("string you're searching", "String you want to find") , len( "string you're searching" ) - InStr("string you're searching", "String you want to find") )

Comment: i dont know the string I have to find, I'll explain it better.. I know "_part" is part of that string. The code should extract all string that contains "_part".
Its like ctrl+f "_part". Then i manually copy paste it. I just want to automate this procedure

Comment: len() = gives you the entire length of the string.
instr() = this is used to find the _part you're looking for.
mid() = with the prior two and the mid statement you can capture as much of the text as you'd like using addition and subtraction.

Comment: Although you could just use excel functions if all you're trying to do is copy and paste a part of a string.